# Pipelight won't appear as Firefox plugin

Tags: firefox, ubuntu

I successfully installed [Pipelight](http://pipelight.net/cms/install/installation-ubuntu.html) in my *Ubuntu Trusty*, but then with my immense joy I could see that *Pipelight* is not listed in my **Firefox** plugins ([about:plugins](http://about:plugins)).

I clearly restarted Firefox after installing Pipelight, and I also rebooted my machine.

Any troubleshooting I could run to find the problem?

Thanks!

PS Could any StackOverflow master create the **Pipelight tag** and tag it here? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Running this command with root privileges helped:

```
sudo pipelight-plugin --create-mozilla-plugins
```

I found the solution here: http://pipelight.net/cms/faqs/faq-pipelight-error-in-aboutplugins.html

Comment: Great.... I also ran `sudo pipelight-plugin --update` beforehand as your link suggests: it probably helped too because during Firefox restart I saw a little popup showing the installation of the _wine-silverlight_ stuff.